# Como recibir y guardar imágenes binarias PHP

Tags: php, api, upload

Estoy creando un servicio de API Rest con php para subir una imagen, para efectos de prueba utilizo el Postman, la petición a la API es un post con un archivo binario en el body (ver la imagen).

[image: Peticion a la API]

Como puedo recibir y guardar la imagen en la ruta deseada con php?

Este es el método donde recibo las peticiones post:

```
public static function  post()
{
    $ruta = "../imagenes";
}
```

He intentado utilizando:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['API-page-graphic.png']['tmp_name'], $ruta . "/" . $_FILES['API-page-graphic.png']['name']);
```

Pero me dispara un error: Undefined index: API-page-graphic.png

También he intentado utilizando:

```
 $file = file_get_contents('php://input');
 file_put_contents($ruta .'/recentImage1.png', base64_decode($file));
```

Esto si crea el archivo pero no se puede leer.

Agradezco de antemano su valiosa ayuda.

Comment: Quieres guardar la image en una Base de Datos?

Comment: Hola @Bicho, la imagen la quiero guardar en un directorio como archivo, no en una base de datos, para después poder acceder a la imagen a través de una url tipo **https://api/imagenes/imagenguardada.png**

Comment: ¿Por qué usas bas64_decode()? Si la imagen viene en "binario" quiere decir que no se ha modificado. Ahora, lo interesante sería ver cómo haces la petición, seguramente ahí se especifica cómo se envía el archivo.

Comment: Que tal @Triby, te asiste la razón, le quite el base64_decode() y ya puedo leer el archivo, muchas gracias! Si no es molestia hay alguna manera de saber el nombre y la extension del archivo que se recibe?

Comment: Si estás tomando todo desde `php://input` mucho me temo que no, porque solo recibes el archivo y no hay posibilidad de enviar otros datos, a menos que los envíes serializados, pero debo insistir en que agregues el código que tienes para realizar la petición.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo una API, el código para realizar la petición lo haría la persona encargada del front-end con axios, yo hago la petición para probar la API con postman, tal y como aparece en la imagen de la pregunta, si tu conoces alguna otra manera de hacer el servicio desde PHP te agradecería el dato, por ahora esta es la manera que se me ha ocurrido, muchas gracias por tus prontas respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a los comentarios recibidos he encontrado la respuesta para la necesidad que tengo, si bien lo que comento Triby funciona perfectamente, también como acertadamente dice no puedo obtener información del archivo recibido por lo que cambie la petición de tal manera que en lugar de enviar un **binary** en el body, envío un **form-data**, quedando de la siguiente manera:

[image: Imagen de la peticion]

Y ahora este código funciona perfectamente:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $ruta . "/" . $_FILES['imagen']['name']);
```

Gracias a todos!